# Jsoup selector syntax for div having same class

Tags: android, parsing, css-selectors, jsoup, selector

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="content">
      <div class="textData">

      </div>
      <div class="textData">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want text from second div with class=textData. I did parsed div id=content.

Here is my doInbackground

```
try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements myin = null;
                myin = document.select("div.horoscopeText:eq(1)");
                desc = myin.text().toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
div#textData:eq(1)
```

`eq(n)` accepts zero-based index of matched elements. Btw, you shouldn't have multiple elements with same id, use `class` for that. Check out [selector syntax documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for more examples.

**EDIT**

For class instead of id, use `div.textData:eq(1)`

Comment: Yes it was class not id. Edited id with class

Comment: @android_sh_jo This works for example from your question. You can try it yourself on http://try.jsoup.org/ . I don't know why it doesn't work with your other data, but you should be able to test everything on that test page, including live urls.

Comment: @android_sh_jo Try seting user agent prior to connecting to url, something like this `Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();`